# installing python module openFlashChart

Tags: python, open-flash-chart, openflashchart2

How to install python module openFlashChart? I am really having trouble installing it. If you have installed it before kindly post how.

The error was module openFlashChart not found. I actually cant find the module to install.

Comment: If you facing some problem then describe the problem. If you get error then paste that error. Community cant get your problem by this description only.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but flash chart is a flash not python. There is no python module dedicated to flash chart. In fact flash chart need some data from server which can be implemented in python.